# Proper way of implementing post import hooks in python-3.4+

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-importlib, import-hooks

I want to modify the import behavior. I found an example with post import hook in the Book "Python Cookbook" by David Beazley and Brian K. Jones, which should suit my problem.

Since the latest edition was published at the times of `python-3.3` the provided example is outdated. I had to modify it myself, so that the code is compatible with `importlib` after `python-3.4`. In the original version in `PostImportFinder` class`find_module(self, fullname, path = None)` is defined and in `PostImportLoader` instead of `create_module()` `load_module()` was defined.
Here is a small reproducible  example:

```py
#postimport.py
import
import importlib
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

_post_import_hooks = defaultdict(list)

class PostImportFinder:
    def __init__(self):
        self._skip=set()
    
    def find_spec(self, fullname, path = None, target = None):
        if fullname in self._skip:
            return None
        self._skip.add(fullname)
        return PostImportLoader(self)


class PostImportLoader:
    def __init__(self, finder):
        self._finder = finder
    
    def create_module(self, spec):
        importlib.import_module(spec.name)
        module = sys.modules[spec.name]
        for func in _post_import_hooks[spec.name]:
            func(module)
        self._finder._skip.remove(spec.name)
        return module
    
def when_imported(names):
    def decorate(func):
        for fullname in names:
            if fullname in sys.modules:
                print(f'importing {fullname}')
                func(sys.modules[fullname])
            else:
                _post_import_hooks[fullname].append(func)
        return func
    return decorate

sys.meta_path.insert(0,PostImportFinder)
```

```py
#postimportfunc.py
from inspect import getmembers, isfunction, isclass
from postimport import when_imported


list_of_module_names = ['simple']
#Some decorator. For example purposes pretty simple
@when_imported(list_of_module_names)
def decorate(mod):
    # Decorate classes
    print(f'module {mod} imported')
```

```py
#simple.py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=42
    
    def bar(self):
        print(self.x)
```

```py
#start.py
import postimportfunc
from simple import A


foo = A()
foo.bar()
```

When I run the `start.py` following error occurs:

```
    runfile('/home/user/reproduce/start.py', wdir='/home/user/reproduce')

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/user/reproduce/start.py", line 2, in <module>
    import postimportfunc

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load_unlocked

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914, in _find_spec

  File "/home/user/reproduce/postimport.py", line 12, in find_spec
    if fullname in self._skip:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_skip'
```

So my questions are obvious: What  am I doing wrong? I simply do not see how `_skip` and `str` are related, since I initialize `_skip` as a set.
Is there another/better approach  how to change postimport behavior for specified modules?

Upd: P.S. I forgot to mention, that I currently use python-3.7 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main cause was a dumb typo in the last line of `postimport.py`.
Instead of:

```py
sys.meta_path.insert(0,PostImportFinder)
```

It should be:

```py
sys.meta_path.insert(0,PostImportFinder()) #DO NOT FORGET PARENTHESIS
```

But it was not the only problem.
I had also to change following things:

In the `PostImportFinder` rename `find_spec(self, fullname, path = None, targer = None)` into `find_module(self, fullname, path = None)`
and in `PostImportLoader` replace `find_spec()`with:

```py
def load_module(self, fullname):
        importlib.import_module(fullname)
        module = sys.modules[fullname]
        for func in _post_import_hooks[fullname]:
            func(module)
        self._finder._skip.remove(fullname)
        return module
```

So,  to sum it up: I should have sticked to the recipe from the book mentioned in the question.